# How to setup Rotativa HTML to PDF in ASP.NET Core 3?

Tags: asp.net-core-3.0, rotativa

It seems `RotativaConfiguration.Setup(env);` is not working anymore in Core 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
RotativaConfiguration.Setup(env.WebRootPath, "Rotativa");
```

"Rotativa" is the folder name housing the wkhtmltoimage.exe and wkhtmltopdf.exe in the root folder "wwwroot"

Answer (score 0):

**Work for me in ASP.NET Core 3.1 Project:**

> Install-Package Rotativa.AspNetCore -Version 1.1.1
> Then in Startup.cs:

```
using IHostingEnvironment = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment;
```

And in public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)

```
RotativaConfiguration.Setup((IHostingEnvironment)env);
```

Answer (score -1):

For Below ASP.NET Core 3 Use:

```
RotativaConfiguration.Setup(env);
```

For ASP.NET Core 3 Use:

```
RotativaConfiguration.Setup(env.WebRootPath, "Rotativa");
```

Add a new folder inside "wwwroot" with name “Rotativa” and inside this folder keep the wkhtmltoimage.exe and wkhtmltopdf.exe files.
Otherwise you will get error

> cannot convert from 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment'